# Jenkins JIRA plugin: how to remove a version?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jira, jira-plugin

In a Jenkins pipeline, I had used `jiraEditVersion` to change the name of an old project version in JIRA (eg: 100.0.001) to a new version (eg: 100.0.001.1234, where 1234 is a build number), but I found that the old version still existed. Are there any ways to remove the old version programmatically? I have checked the JIRA plugin document but cannot find any (https://jenkinsci.github.io/jira-steps-plugin/steps/version/).

Comment: Are you on cloud or Server/Database? Have you looked into using the Jira API to remove the version?

Comment: It is not a single server/database structure, the Jenkins, Jira and Github should be hosted on different VM's somewhere (not sure they are on the cloud or on premise). I am using the `jira-steps-plugin` for Jenkins, the documentation is https://jenkinsci.github.io/jira-steps-plugin/steps/version/ or https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/jira-steps/

Comment: You can determine the hosting type of Jira based on the URL. If it is <companyname>.atlassian.com it is a cloud instance. Either way, I think you should have a look into removing the version from Jira through the Jira API, as it may not be possible using only the Jenkins plugin

Comment: The Jira site is jira.<companyname>.com, so it should not be a cloud instance then. Thanks for your enlightenment, I will try the JIRA REST API approach.